# Lived ever or ever lived

Tags: adverbs

In the following sentence I have to spot the error

> Organic  pulses  are  so  popular today  that  many
>   people wonder how they ever lived without them.

The answer according to my book is **ever should be used  after lived**. But I think it is used correctly with ever meaning here **at any time in the past**

Comment: You are right, and your book is wrong.

Comment: You could actually remove the 'ever' from this sentence, although that reduces the emphasis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form is "... how they ever lived without them."

Saying "... how the lived ever without them." is incorrect syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Although a more archaic phrasing could be '*people wonder how ever they lived without them*' but the *ever* is still before *lived*